# How to add a horizontal scrollbar to an inner div that has a parent div with a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a fixed height, that includes two divs positioned next to each other:

```
<div id="idContainer">
    <div id="idPaneLeft">
    ...
    </div><div id="idPaneRight">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The inner divs have content with the same height that should be scrolled simultaneously with a common vertical scrollbar:

```
div#idContainer {
//...
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This works as expected.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8dy8x4y1/

The width of the content of the right inner div is greater than the div and should be scrolled with a horizontal scrollbar:

```
div#idPaneRight {
    ...
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

However, adding this setting destroys the grid layout and makes it impossible to simultaneously scroll the content of both inner divs with the vertical scrollbar.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/t1wy1vws/

Any suggestions to solve the problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like by default `vertical-align: middle` is being applied.

You just need to apply `vertical-align: top` to the two child element.

And also, `display: inline-block` introduces some white space between the inline block elements. To remove these space, we need to mention the `font-size` of the parent container as `0px` and then again apply the default `font-size` to the inline block child element.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1wy1vws/2/)**

Comment: This will keep the layout only until the (outer) vertical scrollbar is used.